# Same interface, implementation differences

Tags: java, design-patterns

Given:
- Different implementations that need to be gathered under the same interface

Unluck: these implementations have a method 'create', **but with different number and types of input params**

Solutions....?
What other option is there besides varargs of Object?

Comment: You could use a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)

Comment: You can use something like a builder pattern, which may be overkill. But the real problem seem to be in your interface!

Comment: the problem is that I do not have the same number/type of parameters in the method signature....

Comment: Unless the parameter are the same, you can't call it in a consistent manner.  Can you pass the arguments as a Map e.g. `Map<String, Object>` like Properties.

Comment: @Roxana, how do you want the calling code to look? When a caller calls `create`, how will it know what parameters to pass? Where will it have got those variables from? It sounds like the callers will have to know what implementation they're using, which makes an interface pointless here. But tell us a bit more about what you want to do, and we may be able to suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want only one create method under the interface that you are intending

Create a wrapper class that implements the interface you are intending.  Now call the various implementation from wrapper class based on some condition.

**For Maintainabilty Perspective**

If possible avoid conditions and Send the implementation class name from calling code .just call the create method on class passed as argument from calling code.(For this you also need to create the dummy create method with some object class as parameter which contains all the parameters under each implementation class which simply delegates the call to intended method with required number of params )

Answer (score 0):

If the method is so flexible there seems little point in trying to enforce it via an interface . What you could do, though, is implement an interface describing the different types of parameters you want to pass.

e.g.

```
public abstract create(CreateParamsInterface cpi) {};
```

and then implement that abstract method in your class, using the members exposed va `CreateParamsInterface` as relevant.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I am not sure I understand how the interface should be used. Let's say, I have a String for some invocation, and for the other I have Long and BigDecimal.

Answer (score 0):

In the interface provide a method that takes a condition as an argument on basis of which you can decide which version of create you wish to call. Based on the condition you can call the respective  create() function.The logic is same as that of the [Factory design pattern](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/12/factory-design-pattern-java-example.html).

Answer (score 0):

I see three options:

1. You can pass parameters when you *construct* object which has method `create()`. So you just add parameters to constructor of object which implements interface containing `create()`.
2. Modify create so that it will take as argument the object which calls method `create()`. That way you should have interface `create(ObjectWhichWantsCreation x)` and this method would take all necessary data from given object.
3. Make `create(Properties p)` where Properties: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html this is quite generic but you must make sure that they contain needed data.

of course you can modify 2 and 3 so that they have method `create()` and just add another method `setParams(SomeParams...)` which needs to be called first.